# SELECT query where one attribute has a condition and the other one doesn't in the same table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The problem statement is: "Create a query that gives you the total number of employees, and from that total, the total of employees that were hired between 1995-1998 both included".

I managed to think both and tested them, so I know they work separated:

```
SELECT COUNT(employee_id) AS "Total number of employees"
FROM employees
```

for the first question and

```
SELECT COUNT(employee_id) AS "Total between 1995-1198"
FROM employees
WHERE hire_date BETWEEN '1-ENE-1995' AND '31-12-1998';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation. Here is one method:

```
select count(*) as Count_Total,
       sum(case when hire_date >= date '1995-01-01' and hire_date < date '1999-01-01'
                then 1 else 0
           end) as Count1995_1998
from employees;
```

Notes:

- This uses the `date` qualifier for the date.  This allows you to input ISO standard formats in Oracle.  When using dates, use a consistent format.
- This uses explicit comparisons for the date column with `<` for the later date.  This is on purpose.  In Oracle a column with a `date` data type can also contain a time.  The time component can throw queries off.
- Conditional aggregation is the use of the `case` statement in an aggregation function.

Comment: I don't quite understand this sintax as I use oracle sql-developer sintax. Is Count_total is an Alias?, also, why SUM and not COUNT? 
Last, my college teacher has told us that these are basic querys, so we are supposed to be able to do them without methods (we haven't seen them). Could you do an edit on my code so I see it more clear?

Comment: @AliAs . . . `Count_Total` is an alias.  There is no accounting for taste on what a "simple" query is, but this is a pretty simple query.

Comment: @AliAs - yes, `count` can be used instead of `sum` in row #2. What Gordon has shown is the efficient way to write the query, where you get both answers by scanning the table just once. Are you saying you haven't studied the "CASE expression" in class?

Answer (score -1):

As fa as i understand the question 
Sql server : select count(*) from employees where hiredate between (firstDate,endDate)
I wish this is helps you